# Bought a luxury car, just a dev

Tags: company-culture

so I bought an audi a6, but it makes me feel weird into what my colleagues of other departments will think, like I'm earning way too much which I'm not, or have any kind of crazy ideas, besides I'm sort of young age. My dev department knows and I feel cool with that. The reason I want to know how I can handle it is because I think I need to use my office parking lots, and they will ofcourse notice.

Comment: Why did you buy an Audi if you "like the low profile thing"?

Comment: Err, what? Don't like the car, sell it. Do like it, keep it. Problem solved.

Comment: I don't think anyone in your company will judge you for your car, at most you'll get a "nice car" comment from a few colleagues.

Comment: I actually like the car, I just want to know the best way to handle it in my work place @berry120

Comment: Is there a question here? I think you worry more about your car than other people will..

Comment: @HerlandCid Handle it with care. Sounds like it was expensive. On a more serious note, don't make this a problem before it is one. Chances are it never will be.

Comment: I would presume that 'likes low profile' meant they like being low profile at work. They liked a particular car and don't want that to draw extra attention to them. They are just asking how to handle any unwanted attention.

Comment: exactly @n_plum

Comment: Note: you work with programmers. Most of them wouldn’t notice if you rode a pink elephant to work.

Comment: How would they know that it is your car?  And how would they know if you bought, leased, rented, or borrowed the car?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Why would programmers not note a pink elephant? They probably wouldn't mind.

Comment: @sf02 He might park in a spot where he used to park his car all the time.  People see him getting in and out. People see it's an expensive car: it doesn't matter if it is bought or leased - for those who mind.

Comment: Dev I worked with drove a Mercedes convertible, because he once had a huge slot machine win while killing time after a job at a casino. It wasn't weird, but we did make him drive all the time when we went out for lunch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem and you shouldn't make it into one.

Carry on as normal. Drive to work, do your work, drive home from work. Say thank you to those that complement the car. If you're that worried about them judging you for having bought a more expensive vehicle, just add an 'I've been saving for a while and excited to finally get it!'. You don't need to justify what you've done to anyone at work.

Comment: In short terms to me it's like, to work in the fear of being judge by others by any reason. I appreciate all responses.

Comment: @HerlandCid Well that fear is going to be there no matter what, partly because we all think it, and partly because your personality places importance on it (too much).  Tell that fear to shut up.